# Advanced substitute in excel with range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, substitution

I'm trying to replace 1400 cells with text into cells with ids, I've attached a picture so you can understand it easier. I'm trying to do this only by using cells because I have 1400 cells I need to replace.

I've trying using substitute using a range but I can't seem to make it work.
`=SUBSTITUTE(H2;K2:K999;J2:J999)`
[image: example]

Comment: I agree with @pnuts. A short VBA code can do what you want in a blink of an eye but of course only if you want to take that route. Also I think an array formula is possible (not really sure), but let me try it first and get back to you.

Comment: I don't mind using VBA code, I don't know why I typed "only by using cells", my intention was different. If you don't mind sharing a VBA code, maybe it will suit other people better :). I'll stick with the solution @mock_blatt posted for now!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to use a VBA solution?

If you don't mind moving some stuff around, try this.

[image: Using repeated substitute formula, needs to use up a column for each lookup you have. Once you put the formula in correctly in the first cell, you can drag it to the right, and drag the whole thing down. Your desired result will be in the last cell to the right]

Damn, that image isn't big enough, is it? You can see the layout though. "Original Text" is in C1, and the word ID is in A5, and I've numbered D1:I1 1-6. Now paste this formula into D2: =SUBSTITUTE(C2,OFFSET($B$6,D$1-1,0),OFFSET($A$6,D$1-1,0))

And drag it right and drag all the columns down. Your desired output should be in column I. It's not the most computationally efficient, but it's super easy to implement and works with any size lookup table (just drag out more columns and number them) and any number of items in the text fields.

Comment: Yes the image is legible, your solution works! But as you've said, it's not the most efficient way but it works :) Thank you so much.